# Difference between fixing a variable and using a constant in GEKKO

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, gekko

I am solving a large scale optimization problem using Python GEKKO. Some variables of the model have to not change during the optimization process. So I was wondering what is the difference between using the `m.fix` GEKKO method on the variables (`m.Var`) that I want to be constant, or replacing the variables with constants declared with `m.Const`.

I use IMODE = 3 (default) as I do not do anything that requires simulation or estimation, derivatives, time, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When possible, it is best to use `int` or `float` numbers in the model for large-scale problems. It is also possible to use `m.Const()` or `m.Var()` and fix the value. The `m.Var()` option is least efficient because it builds the 1st and 2nd derivative information with operator overloading. If you do need to include simple equations, such as used with `c4` definition, then use `m.options.REDUCE=1` to do a pre-solve to identify and eliminate variables that associated with simple pre-solvable constraints. Setting `m.options.REDUCE=2` scans the model twice and it is possible to do additional scans.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()

c1 = 2.0
c2 = m.Const(3.0)
c3 = m.Var(); m.fix(c3,4.0)
c4 = m.Var(); m.Equation(c4==5)

v = m.Var()
m.Minimize((v-c1-c2-c3-c4)**2)
m.solve(disp=False)
print(c1,c2.value,c3.value[0],c4.value[0],v.value[0])
```

Results:

```
2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 14.0
```

**Constant definition for improved model performance**

- Best: `c1` - Python number
- 2nd Best: `c2` - Gekko constant
- 3rd Best: `c3` - Gekko variable, fixed
- Worst: `c4` - Gekko variable, equation

Comment: What I was doing now was first declaring all the variables and then fixing the necessary ones, so to make it more efficient (by using `m.Const` instead of `m.fix`) I wanted to replace things like `m.fix(c3,4.0)` by `c3 = m.Const(c3.value)` (this is before calling solve). However, I get "ValueError: Constant value must be scalar.". If I use `c3.value[0]` I get another error "TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable". I've also tried doing `float(c3.value)`, but I also get an error:  "TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'GK_Value'". Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: OK, I think that `c3.value.value` works.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution. We have to keep track of whether a value changes so c3.value has c3.value.value and c3.value.change